# Show Block class image upload to Ui form image upload

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, image, adminform

How can i change **from this**

[image]

**To this**

[image]

My Code to create image upload is below. I don't want to create the form with UI component but i want to make the image upload like it.

```
    $fieldset->addField(
        'outfit_image',
        'image',
        [
            'name' => 'outfit_image',
            'label' => __('Outfit Image'),
            'title' => __('Outfit Image'),
            'required' => true,
        ]
    );
```

Comment: Which magento version are you using?

Comment: magento 2.3.1 version

Comment: If you want to do using `$fieldset` method then you have do more customization if it is possible then  go with Ui-component it will take less time to finish it.

Comment: What customization do i need to do?

Comment: I have not try ever to do customization like this but as per your requirement i think there is need more customization.